# Can't build ipa_canopen

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to set up communication with a pair of Schunk Light Weight Robot Arms purchased back in 2007. I have set up a catkin work space with:

- cob_common
- cob_extern
- ipa_canopen
- schunk_modular_robotics
- schunk_robots

When I run catkin_make I get the following build error:

```
[ 98%] Built target schunk_powercube_chain
/home/parallels/catkin_ws/src/ipa_canopen/ipa_canopen_ros/src/ipa_canopen_ros.cpp:66:30: fatal error: cob_srvs/Trigger.h: No such file or directory
 #include "cob_srvs/Trigger.h"
                              ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [ipa_canopen/ipa_canopen_ros/CMakeFiles/ipa_canopen_ros.dir/src/ipa_canopen_ros.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ipa_canopen/ipa_canopen_ros/CMakeFiles/ipa_canopen_ros.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make install -j2 -l2" failed
```

"remove Trigger from cob_srvs" is included in one of the most recent changes of the `cob_srvs` change log. I'm new to ROS and it may be that I'm not following the correct procedure in terms of cloning and installing packages. I've assumed that once I've cloned them into my workspace and run `catkin_make` that I can begin to incorporate their functionality into my own package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227840/can%27t-build-ipa_canopen/) by [gracecopplestone](https://answers.ros.org/users/26005/gracecopplestone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-02-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gracecopplestone](https://answers.ros.org/users/26005/gracecopplestone/) on 2016-02-29**:
Solved this by replacing my version of cob_srvs with the 0.6.2 release on Github, from before Trigger.h had been removed. Was then able to run catkin_make successfully.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-01**:
@gracecopplestone: can you please report this on either [ipa320/ipa_canopen](https://github.com/ipa320/ipa_canopen/issues) or [ros-industrial/ros_canopen](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_canopen/issues)? This is really a bug/error.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`ipa_canopen` ist not supported on indigo (we will remove the branches soon).

LWA3 is using `schunk_powercube_chain`, LWA4 was migrated to `ros_canopen` with example configs in `schunk_robots`. In both cases you don't need `ipa_canopen`.

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2016-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gracecopplestone](https://answers.ros.org/users/26005/gracecopplestone/) on 2016-03-01**:
We're struggling to figure out which model we actually have. From your experiences with Schunk would you know which model this is? http://i1285.photobucket.com/albums/a584/copplestone/IMG_20160224_092226%201_zpsjpwafoxg.jpg

**Comment by [Felix Messmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/208/felix-messmer/) on 2016-03-01**:
Unfortunately, I don't know this arm. It's none of the ones with example files in [schunk_robots](https://github.com/ipa320/schunk_robots). Ask Schunk directly!
But if you are going to use ROS with it, you will most likely also face the problem that no [URDF](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf) exists (yet).

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2016-03-01**:
I don't know this model either, but it is definitely no CANopen arm.
So `schunk_powercube_chain` might work, but it really depends on the model.

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2016-03-01**:
I believe your arm is a LWA2 (http://www.schunk.com/schunk_files/attachments/PW_090_EN_z.pdf, page 3, looks famillar).

**Comment by [gracecopplestone](https://answers.ros.org/users/26005/gracecopplestone/) on 2016-03-01**:
Thanks for your answers. So if I understand correctly, if we are able to create our own URDF, there's a chance we could use it with schunk_powercube_chain?

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2016-03-01**:
Yes, there is a chance. You could try the powercube software (http://www.schunk.com/schunk/schunk_websites/service/downloads.html?submenu=215&submenu2=0&country=INT&lngCode=EN&lngCode2=EN#11915) on windows to verify the protocol.

**Comment by [gracecopplestone](https://answers.ros.org/users/26005/gracecopplestone/) on 2016-03-01**:
OK, to confirm, we have successfully established communication using the powercube software and hex code from the "Data exchange with Powercube" document via the PEAK CAN-USB and ESD PCI board. Now trying to figure whether there are pre-existing ROS packages to replicate comms and movement.

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2016-03-02**:
Then http://wiki.ros.org/schunk_powercube_chain should be worth a try :)
You don't need a URDF for it, just the config.

**Comment by [gracecopplestone](https://answers.ros.org/users/26005/gracecopplestone/) on 2016-03-02**:
Thanks, so if schunk_powercube_chain controls subscription and publishing of joint velocity/states, will I need to incorporate separate packages to handle inverse kinematics?

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2016-03-02**:
`schunk_powercube_chain`just provides joint states and a velocity interface. `cob_trajectory_controller` provides a trajectory action on top of it.
For kinematics you have to write a URDF, the tf system will give you the FK. For IK you have to use MoveIt! or any other available option.

**Comment by [gracecopplestone](https://answers.ros.org/users/26005/gracecopplestone/) on 2016-03-03**:
Great, so last part of the puzzle is which package acts as the driver and actually transmits and receives the hexcode via the CAN-USB adaptor or PCI card? Or does schunk_powercube_chain already take care of that in it's available topics?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved this by replacing my version of cob_srvs with the 0.6.2 release on Github, from before Trigger.h had been removed. Was then able to run catkin_make successfully.

---

Originally posted by [gracecopplestone](https://answers.ros.org/users/26005/gracecopplestone/) with karma: 31 on 2016-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2